# JavaScriptでIDやClassではない要素の取得

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div id="A" class="B" hoge="C">
```

以上の要素を取得したいのですが

```
document.getElementById('B');
document.getElementsByClassName('A');
```

以上のようなIDやClassから取得するのではなく『hoge="C"』から取得すにはどうすれば良いですか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) もしくは [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) が希望する機能を持ちます。CSSセレクターで表現できる内容であれば要素を取得できます。

```
// 最初のみ
document.querySelector('[hoge="C"]');
// 該当するすべて
document.querySelectorAll('[hoge="C"]');
```

Comment: 確かに動作しました。初歩的なことすら分からない中ご親切にありがとうございます！